# Difficulty with for if statement

Tags: python

Write a function named "find_value" that takes a list of integers as a parameter and searches for the value 8. The function will return a boolean value representing true if 8 is in the list and false if it is not.

```
def find_value(number):
    for i in number:
        if i in number is 8:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

function find_value incorrect on input [[11, 3, 11, 1, 8, 12]]
returned: False
expected: True

Comment: if you don't post an attempt at the problem, we can't really help you. not here to do your homework :/

Comment: I just did above. def find_value(number): for i in number: if i in number is 8: return True else: return False

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow demands that one does the necessary homework before posting a question. Since, you're a new contributor - here's one solution. But strongly recommend to read the guidelines.

**Sample code:**

```
def find_value(number):
  return bool(8 in number)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> find_value([1,2,3,4])
False
>>> find_value([1,2,3,4, 8])
True
>>> find_value([])
False
>>>
```

Comment: you don't necessarily need that `bool`

Comment: Agree Kevin. Overlooked - my bad! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will *filter* the list using *lambda* for `x==8`. Then `any` will return `True` if any items populated the filtered list or `False` if not

```
print(any(list(filter(lambda x: x == 8, [11, 3, 11, 1, 8, 12])))) # => True
```